# AngularJS: promise in a loop

Tags: angularjs, loops, user-interface, promise, q

I am unable to do the promise looping.

I make a service call to get list of providers, then for each provider, I make another service call to get a customer.

A provider has 1 or more customers. So eventual list of customer is to be decorated and displayed.

In other format I am trying to achieve:

```
*serviceA.getProvider(){

  foreach(providers){

   foreach(provider.customerID){

    serviceB.getCustomer(customerId)

   }

  }

}
.then( 

  foreach(Customer){

   updateTheCustomer;

   addUpdatedCustomerToAList

  }

displayUpdatedCustomreList();

)*
```

I have written following code, that isn't working

```
doTheJob(model: Object) {
    let A = [];
    let B = [];

let fetchP = function(obj) {
  obj.Service1.fetchAllP().then(function (response) {
    let P = cloneDeep(response.data);

    _.forEach(P, function(prov) {
      _.forEach(prov.CIds, function(Id) {
        A.push(Id);
      });
    });

    _.forEach(A, function(CId) {
      return obj.Service2.getById(CId);//what works is if this statement was: return obj.Service2.getById(A[0]);
                                        //So, clearly, returning promise inside loop isn't working
    });
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    B.push(response.data); //This response is undefined

    angular.forEach(B, function (value) {
      obj.updateAdr(value)
    });

    obj.dispay(B);
  });
};
fetchP(this);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` don't stop when you use `return` inside of it, try to use a plain loop instead, why you don't just loop with `for` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
_.forEach(A, function(CId) {
   return obj.Service2.getById(CId);
}
```

as stated by @Ze Rubeus if you return inside a callback within a for loop that value will be lost, since it's not returned to the caller.

probably you wanted something like this

```
return Promise.all(A.map(function(CId){
   //collect each promise inside an array that will then be resolved
   return obj.Service2.getById(CId);
})
```

Comment: Karim, you are star! Your solution worked absolutely amazing! Thanks